# NSTimer Don't Accept ToInt()

Tags: macos, swift, nstimer

I was trying to `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. I have string and i'm getting the int with `substringToIndex` then im converting to int value with `toInt()` but NSTimer don't accept.

```
var Time = CleanText.substringToIndex(advance(CleanText.startIndex, 2))
let time2:Int = Time.toInt()!

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time2, target: self, selector: Selector(""), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

what is the solution?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)? What is the type of the first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

this is the prototype of NSTimer.schdeuledTimerWithTimeInterval

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti invocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

where **ti** parameter is of type **NSTimeInterval** which is in turn a **double**...

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

So instead of integer use double

like 2.0 instead of 2